# Can't display OpenGL in Qwidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I want to make simple opengl project as in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nzHSkY4K18&feature=player_detailpage) tutorial.

I add new class GLWidget that inherit from QGLWidget, and promote my QWidget object to GLWidget class that i already made. When i run project i can't refresh QWidget object. Every time i see what's behind that window when I build and run project.

This is how it should look like [Correct](http://pl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2md4113&s=8#.VETjRcnFabF) 
And this is what it really looks [not correct](http://pl.tinypic.com/r/2cfeg4o/8)
.

GLWidget.h

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QTimer>

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    GLWidget(int width, int height);

    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);

private:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *);
};

#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

GlWidget.cpp

```
#include "glwidget.h"
#include<QMessageBox>
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)
{
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    // Init Glew
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    GLenum error = glewInit();
    if(error != GLEW_OK)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    glClearColor( 0.2f, 0.45f, 0.8f, 1.0f ); // blue background
    glClearDepth( 1.0f );
}

GLWidget::GLWidget(int width, int height) : QGLWidget()
{
    startTimer(30);
    resize(width, height);
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void GLWidget::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *)
{
    updateGL();
}
```

Mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-10-16T20:17:33
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Manipulatorv2
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    glwidget.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    glwidget.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += "/home/szczepan/glew-1.11.0/include"

LIBS += -L"/home/szczepan/glew-1.11.0/lib"-lGLEW
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the GLWidget you should override the `paintGL` and do a `glClearBuffer` with the correct bits set in the argument. Otherwise it will just take whatever was in the buffer at the time.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example to create with `Qt`, a simple class named `OpenGLWindow` from `QGLWidget`:

#### configure .pro

Download the GLEW library according to  your OpenGL Version : [Glew library](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)

For instance, if I choose **glew-1.5.6**:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "path/to/glew-1.5.6/include"
LIBS += -L"path/to/glew-1.5.6/lib" -lGLEW     #UNIX
LIBS += -L"path/to/glew-1.5.6/lib" -lglew32   #WINDOWS
```

With windows, you have to place **glew32.dll** in the same folder that your .**exe**.

#### openglwindow.h

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QTimerEvent>

class OpenGLWindow : public QGLWidget
{
public:
    OpenGLWindow(int width, int height);
    ~OpenGLWindow();

    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);

private:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *);
};
```

#### openglwindow.cpp

```
OpenGLWindow::OpenGLWindow(int width, int height) : QGLWidget()
{
    startTimer(30);
    resize(width, height);
}

OpenGLWindow::~OpenGLWindow()
{
}

void OpenGLWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *)
{
    updateGL();
}

void OpenGLWindow::initializeGL()
{
    // Init Glew
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    GLenum error = glewInit();
    if(error != GLEW_OK)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    glClearColor( 0.2f, 0.45f, 0.8f, 1.0f ); // blue background
    glClearDepth( 1.0f );
}

void OpenGLWindow::paintGL()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
}

void OpenGLWindow::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Hope this code will be helpful.

Comment: `glClearColor`/`Depth` should, in most cases, go into `initializeGL`, or at least before `glClear`.

Comment: It doesn't change the result but you're right, it's a better way.

Comment: glwidget.h:4: error: GL/glew: No such file or directory
#include <GL/glew>. glew is a part of QTCreator in previous versions? I take QT Creator because I was thinking it was bether to stars. I have also Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. What is bether? On internet i got 100 tutorials of old versions of OpenGl and when I try new "bether opengl" it's always failre.

Comment: GLEW is the main library you need, to use new OpenGL features. I prefer use Qt because I started to learn OpenGL with. Take a look, I just edit my post.